# how to write test for breaking down (RTP depayload or parsed) JPEG frame into RTP (RFC 2435)

Tags: udp, jpeg, rtp

I am a bit new and still learning about socket and RTP stuff.  Basically, i want to write a program that can send a jpeg (ultimately gonna be mjpeg) through RTP using UDP protocol.

I have the program for UDP and be able to send files or stream to a local address (127.0.0.1) using openCV. ok. So that is not a problem.

However, when i try to pass the frame that capture through  VideoCapture from openCV, it wont work. Or rather i have no idea how to do it to be exact.

So now, i want to break this problem down and decide to test only on the RTP side.

So as you can see in my main function, i tried to test out the functions but it doesn't look like it works.

Can someone point me to the right direction of how to properly test those function, specially the sendFrame one ? 
This code mainly just copy and paste from RFC2435 document.

Thanks

```
`/*
 * Table K.1 from JPEG spec.
 */
static const int jpeg_luma_quantizer[64] = {
        16, 11, 10, 16, 24, 40, 51, 61,
        12, 12, 14, 19, 26, 58, 60, 55,
        14, 13, 16, 24, 40, 57, 69, 56,
        14, 17, 22, 29, 51, 87, 80, 62,
        18, 22, 37, 56, 68, 109, 103, 77,
        24, 35, 55, 64, 81, 104, 113, 92,
        49, 64, 78, 87, 103, 121, 120, 101,
        72, 92, 95, 98, 112, 100, 103, 99
};
`
/*
 * Table K.2 from JPEG spec.
 */

    static const int jpeg_chroma_quantizer[64] = {
        17, 18, 24, 47, 99, 99, 99, 99,
        18, 21, 26, 66, 99, 99, 99, 99,
        24, 26, 56, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99,
        47, 66, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99,
        99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99,
        99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99,
        99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99,
        99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99
};

    int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    //setup openCV
        cvNamedWindow("UDP Video Sender", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
        if(!capture){
            std::cout<<"No camera found."<< std::endl;
            goto DONE;
        }
        IplImage *frame;
            frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
            IplImage *small = cvCreateImage(cvSize(frame->width / 2, frame->height / 2),
                frame->depth, 3);

      while(1){
                //capture frame and resize
                frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
                cvResize(frame, small, CV_INTER_LINEAR);
                cvShowImage("UDP Video Sender", small);


    //MakeHeaders(filename,0,5,5,0,128,0);

    //MakeTables(128,frame,0);

    //MakeDRIHeader();

   // MakeHuffmanHeader();
                MakeHuffmanHeader(128,1024,1024,uchar *lum_ac_symbols[],1024,1,1 );
    //MakeQuantHeader();
DONE:
    cout<<"Press any key to continue."<<endl;

}
}



/*
 * Call MakeTables with the Q factor and two u_char[64] return arrays
 */
void
MakeTables(int q, u_char *lqt, u_char *cqt)
{
  int i;
  int factor = q;

  if (q < 1) factor = 1;
  if (q > 99) factor = 99;
  if (q < 50)
    q = 5000 / factor;
  else
    q = 200 - factor*2;
  for (i=0; i < 64; i++) {
    int lq = (jpeg_luma_quantizer[i] * q + 50) / 100;
    int cq = (jpeg_chroma_quantizer[i] * q + 50) / 100;

    /* Limit the quantizers to 1 <= q <= 255 */
    if (lq < 1) lq = 1;
    else if (lq > 255) lq = 255;
    lqt[i] = lq;

    if (cq < 1) cq = 1;
    else if (cq > 255) cq = 255;
    cqt[i] = cq;
  }
}

/**The following routines can be used to create the JPEG marker segments
   corresponding to the table-specification data that is absent from the
   RTP/JPEG body.
*/
u_char lum_dc_codelens[] = {
        0, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
};

u_char lum_dc_symbols[] = {
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
};

u_char lum_ac_codelens[] = {
        0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0x7d,
};

u_char lum_ac_symbols[] = {
        0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x00, 0x04, 0x11, 0x05, 0x12,
        0x21, 0x31, 0x41, 0x06, 0x13, 0x51, 0x61, 0x07,
        0x22, 0x71, 0x14, 0x32, 0x81, 0x91, 0xa1, 0x08,
        0x23, 0x42, 0xb1, 0xc1, 0x15, 0x52, 0xd1, 0xf0,
        0x24, 0x33, 0x62, 0x72, 0x82, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x16,
        0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27, 0x28,
        0x29, 0x2a, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39,
        0x3a, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x49,
        0x4a, 0x53, 0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57, 0x58, 0x59,
        0x5a, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 0x68, 0x69,
        0x6a, 0x73, 0x74, 0x75, 0x76, 0x77, 0x78, 0x79,
        0x7a, 0x83, 0x84, 0x85, 0x86, 0x87, 0x88, 0x89,
        0x8a, 0x92, 0x93, 0x94, 0x95, 0x96, 0x97, 0x98,
        0x99, 0x9a, 0xa2, 0xa3, 0xa4, 0xa5, 0xa6, 0xa7,
        0xa8, 0xa9, 0xaa, 0xb2, 0xb3, 0xb4, 0xb5, 0xb6,
        0xb7, 0xb8, 0xb9, 0xba, 0xc2, 0xc3, 0xc4, 0xc5,
        0xc6, 0xc7, 0xc8, 0xc9, 0xca, 0xd2, 0xd3, 0xd4,
        0xd5, 0xd6, 0xd7, 0xd8, 0xd9, 0xda, 0xe1, 0xe2,
        0xe3, 0xe4, 0xe5, 0xe6, 0xe7, 0xe8, 0xe9, 0xea,
        0xf1, 0xf2, 0xf3, 0xf4, 0xf5, 0xf6, 0xf7, 0xf8,
        0xf9, 0xfa,
};

u_char chm_dc_codelens[] = {
        0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
};

u_char chm_dc_symbols[] = {
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,

};

u_char chm_ac_codelens[] = {
        0, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 7, 5, 4, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0x77,
};

u_char chm_ac_symbols[] = {
        0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x11, 0x04, 0x05, 0x21,
        0x31, 0x06, 0x12, 0x41, 0x51, 0x07, 0x61, 0x71,
        0x13, 0x22, 0x32, 0x81, 0x08, 0x14, 0x42, 0x91,
        0xa1, 0xb1, 0xc1, 0x09, 0x23, 0x33, 0x52, 0xf0,
        0x15, 0x62, 0x72, 0xd1, 0x0a, 0x16, 0x24, 0x34,
        0xe1, 0x25, 0xf1, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x26,
        0x27, 0x28, 0x29, 0x2a, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38,
        0x39, 0x3a, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48,
        0x49, 0x4a, 0x53, 0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57, 0x58,
        0x59, 0x5a, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 0x68,
        0x69, 0x6a, 0x73, 0x74, 0x75, 0x76, 0x77, 0x78,
        0x79, 0x7a, 0x82, 0x83, 0x84, 0x85, 0x86, 0x87,
        0x88, 0x89, 0x8a, 0x92, 0x93, 0x94, 0x95, 0x96,
        0x97, 0x98, 0x99, 0x9a, 0xa2, 0xa3, 0xa4, 0xa5,
        0xa6, 0xa7, 0xa8, 0xa9, 0xaa, 0xb2, 0xb3, 0xb4,
        0xb5, 0xb6, 0xb7, 0xb8, 0xb9, 0xba, 0xc2, 0xc3,
        0xc4, 0xc5, 0xc6, 0xc7, 0xc8, 0xc9, 0xca, 0xd2,
        0xd3, 0xd4, 0xd5, 0xd6, 0xd7, 0xd8, 0xd9, 0xda,
        0xe2, 0xe3, 0xe4, 0xe5, 0xe6, 0xe7, 0xe8, 0xe9,
        0xea, 0xf2, 0xf3, 0xf4, 0xf5, 0xf6, 0xf7, 0xf8,
        0xf9, 0xfa,
};

u_char *
MakeQuantHeader(u_char *p, u_char *qt, int tableNo)
{
        *p++ = 0xff;
        *p++ = 0xdb;            /* DQT */
        *p++ = 0;               /* length msb */
        *p++ = 67;              /* length lsb */
        *p++ = tableNo;
        memcpy(p, qt, 64);
        return (p + 64);
}

u_char *
MakeHuffmanHeader(u_char *p, u_char *codelens, int ncodes,
                  u_char *symbols, int nsymbols, int tableNo,
                  int tableClass)
{
        *p++ = 0xff;
    *p++ = 0xc4;            /* DHT */
            *p++ = 0;               /* length msb */
            *p++ = 3 + ncodes + nsymbols; /* length lsb */
            *p++ = (tableClass << 4) | tableNo;
            memcpy(p, codelens, ncodes);
            p += ncodes;
            memcpy(p, symbols, nsymbols);
            p += nsymbols;
            return (p);
    }

    u_char *
    MakeDRIHeader(u_char *p, u_short dri) {
            *p++ = 0xff;
            *p++ = 0xdd;            /* DRI */
            *p++ = 0x0;             /* length msb */
            *p++ = 4;               /* length lsb */
            *p++ = dri >> 8;        /* dri msb */
            *p++ = dri & 0xff;      /* dri lsb */
            return (p);
    }

    /*
     *  Arguments:
     *    type, width, height: as supplied in RTP/JPEG header
     *    lqt, cqt: quantization tables as either derived from
     *         the Q field using MakeTables() or as specified
     *         in section 4.2.
     *    dri: restart interval in MCUs, or 0 if no restarts.
     *
     *    p: pointer to return area
     *
     *  Return value:
     *    The length of the generated headers.
     *
     *    Generate a frame and scan headers that can be prepended to the
     *    RTP/JPEG data payload to produce a JPEG compressed image in
     *    interchange format (except for possible trailing garbage and
     *    absence of an EOI marker to terminate the scan).
     */
    int MakeHeaders(u_char *p, int type, int w, int h, u_char *lqt,
                    u_char *cqt, u_short dri)
    {
            u_char *start = p;

            /* convert from blocks to pixels */
            w <<= 3;
            h <<= 3;
            *p++ = 0xff;
                    *p++ = 0xd8;            /* SOI */

                    p = MakeQuantHeader(p, lqt, 0);
                    p = MakeQuantHeader(p, cqt, 1);

                    if (dri != 0)
                            p = MakeDRIHeader(p, dri);

                    *p++ = 0xff;
                    *p++ = 0xc0;            /* SOF */
                    *p++ = 0;               /* length msb */
                    *p++ = 17;              /* length lsb */
                    *p++ = 8;               /* 8-bit precision */
                    *p++ = h >> 8;          /* height msb */
                    *p++ = h;               /* height lsb */
                    *p++ = w >> 8;          /* width msb */
                    *p++ = w;               /* wudth lsb */
                    *p++ = 3;               /* number of components */
                    *p++ = 0;               /* comp 0 */
                    if (type == 0)
                            *p++ = 0x21;    /* hsamp = 2, vsamp = 1 */
                    else
                            *p++ = 0x22;    /* hsamp = 2, vsamp = 2 */
                    *p++ = 0;               /* quant table 0 */
                    *p++ = 1;               /* comp 1 */
                    *p++ = 0x11;            /* hsamp = 1, vsamp = 1 */
                    *p++ = 1;               /* quant table 1 */
                    *p++ = 2;               /* comp 2 */
                    *p++ = 0x11;            /* hsamp = 1, vsamp = 1 */
                    *p++ = 1;               /* quant table 1 */
                    p = MakeHuffmanHeader(p, lum_dc_codelens,
                                          sizeof(lum_dc_codelens),
                                          lum_dc_symbols,
                                          sizeof(lum_dc_symbols), 0, 0);
                    p = MakeHuffmanHeader(p, lum_ac_codelens,
                                          sizeof(lum_ac_codelens),
                                          lum_ac_symbols,
                                          sizeof(lum_ac_symbols), 0, 1);
                    p = MakeHuffmanHeader(p, chm_dc_codelens,
                                          sizeof(chm_dc_codelens),
                                          chm_dc_symbols,
                                          sizeof(chm_dc_symbols), 1, 0);
                    p = MakeHuffmanHeader(p, chm_ac_codelens,
                                          sizeof(chm_ac_codelens),
                                          chm_ac_symbols,
                                          sizeof(chm_ac_symbols), 1, 1);
                    *p++ = 0xff;
                           *p++ = 0xda;            /* SOS */
                           *p++ = 0;               /* length msb */
                           *p++ = 12;              /* length lsb */
                           *p++ = 3;               /* 3 components */
                           *p++ = 0;               /* comp 0 */
                           *p++ = 0;               /* huffman table 0 */
                           *p++ = 1;               /* comp 1 */
                           *p++ = 0x11;            /* huffman table 1 */
                           *p++ = 2;               /* comp 2 */
                           *p++ = 0x11;            /* huffman table 1 */
                           *p++ = 0;               /* first DCT coeff */
                           *p++ = 63;              /* last DCT coeff */
                           *p++ = 0;               /* sucessive approx. */

                           return (p - start);
                   };



    /*
     * RTP data header from RFC1889
     */
    typedef struct {
            unsigned int version:2;   /* protocol version */
            unsigned int p:1;         /* padding flag */
            unsigned int x:1;         /* header extension flag */
            unsigned int cc:4;        /* CSRC count */
            unsigned int m:1;         /* marker bit */
            unsigned int pt:7;        /* payload type */
            u_int16_t seq;              /* sequence number */
            u_int32_t ts;               /* timestamp */
            u_int32_t ssrc;             /* synchronization source */
            u_int32_t csrc[1];          /* optional CSRC list */
    } rtp_hdr_t;

    #define RTP_HDR_SZ 12

    /* The following definition is from RFC1890 */
    #define RTP_PT_JPEG             26

    struct jpeghdr {
            unsigned int tspec:8;   /* type-specific field */
            unsigned int off:24;    /* fragment byte offset */
            u_int8_t type;            /* id of jpeg decoder params */
            u_int8_t q;               /* quantization factor (or table id) */
            u_int8_t width;           /* frame width in 8 pixel blocks */
            u_int8_t height;          /* frame height in 8 pixel blocks */
    };

    struct jpeghdr_rst {
            u_int16_t dri;
            unsigned int f:1;
            unsigned int l:1;
            unsigned int count:14;
    };


    struct jpeghdr_qtable {
            u_int8_t  mbz;
            u_int8_t  precision;
            u_int16_t length;
    };

    #define RTP_JPEG_RESTART           0x40

    /* Procedure SendFrame:
     *
     *  Arguments:
     *    start_seq: The sequence number for the first packet of the current
     *               frame.
     *    ts: RTP timestamp for the current frame
     *    ssrc: RTP SSRC value
     *    jpeg_data: Huffman encoded JPEG scan data
     *    len: Length of the JPEG scan data
     *    type: The value the RTP/JPEG type field should be set to
     *    typespec: The value the RTP/JPEG type-specific field should be set
     *              to
     *    width: The width in pixels of the JPEG image
     *    height: The height in pixels of the JPEG image
     *    dri: The number of MCUs between restart markers (or 0 if there
     *         are no restart markers in the data
     *    q: The Q factor of the data, to be specified using the Independent
     *       JPEG group's algorithm if 1 <= q <= 99, specified explicitly
     *       with lqt and cqt if q >= 128, or undefined otherwise.
     *    lqt: The quantization table for the luminance channel if q >= 128
     *    cqt: The quantization table for the chrominance channels if
     *         q >= 128
     *
     *  Return value:
     *    the sequence number to be sent for the first packet of the next
     *    frame.
     *
     * The following are assumed to be defined:
     *
     * PACKET_SIZE                         - The size of the outgoing packet
     * send_packet(u_int8_t *data, int len)  - Sends the packet to the network
     */
#define PACKET_SIZE 512
    u_int16_t SendFrame(u_int16_t start_seq, u_int32_t ts, u_int32_t ssrc,
                       u_int8_t *jpeg_data, int len, u_int8_t type,
                       u_int8_t typespec, int width, int height, int dri,
                       u_int8_t q, u_int8_t *lqt, u_int8_t *cqt) {
            rtp_hdr_t rtphdr;
            struct jpeghdr jpghdr;
            struct jpeghdr_rst rsthdr;
            struct jpeghdr_qtable qtblhdr;

                  u_int8_t packet_buf[PACKET_SIZE];
                  u_int8_t *ptr;
                  int bytes_left = len;
                  int seq = start_seq;
                  int pkt_len, data_len;

                  /* Initialize RTP header
                   */
                  rtphdr.version = 2;
                  rtphdr.p = 0;
                  rtphdr.x = 0;
                  rtphdr.cc = 0;
                  rtphdr.m = 0;
                  rtphdr.pt = RTP_PT_JPEG;
                  rtphdr.seq = start_seq;
                  rtphdr.ts = ts;
                  rtphdr.ssrc = ssrc;

                  /* Initialize JPEG header
                   */
                  jpghdr.tspec = typespec;
                  jpghdr.off = 0;
                  jpghdr.type = type | ((dri != 0) ? RTP_JPEG_RESTART : 0);
                  jpghdr.q = q;
                  jpghdr.width = width / 8;
                  jpghdr.height = height / 8;

                  /* Initialize DRI header
                   */
                  if (dri != 0) {
                          rsthdr.dri = dri;
                          rsthdr.f = 1;        /* This code does not align RIs */
                          rsthdr.l = 1;
                          rsthdr.count = 0x3fff;
                  }

                  /* Initialize quantization table header
                   */
                  if (q >= 128) {
                          qtblhdr.mbz = 0;
                          qtblhdr.precision = 0; /* This code uses 8 bit tables only */
                          qtblhdr.length = 128;  /* 2 64-byte tables */
                  }

                  while (bytes_left > 0) {
                      ptr = packet_buf + RTP_HDR_SZ;
                      jpghdr.off = htonl(jpghdr.off);
                      /*convert offset in hdr to network order, copy to packet*/
                      memcpy(ptr, &jpghdr, sizeof(jpghdr));
                      jpghdr.off = ntohl(jpghdr.off);

                      ptr += sizeof(jpghdr);

                      data_len = PACKET_SIZE - (ptr - packet_buf);
                      if (data_len >= bytes_left) {
                        data_len = bytes_left;
                        rtphdr.m = 1;
                      }

                      rtphdr.seq = htons(rtphdr.seq);
                      memcpy(packet_buf, &rtphdr, RTP_HDR_SZ);
                      memcpy(ptr, jpeg_data + jpghdr.off, data_len);

                      if(((ptr-packet_buf)+data_len) &&
                         send(sock[0], packet_buf, (ptr - packet_buf) + data_len, 0)<0)
                        perror("hre");
                      jpghdr.off += data_len;
                      bytes_left -= data_len;
                      rtphdr.seq = ntohs(rtphdr.seq);
                      rtphdr.seq++;
                    }
                    free(packet_buf);
                    return rtphdr.seq;
 }
```

Comment: why no ffmpeg ? is there a concrete reason to reinvent the wheel ?

Comment: mainly because of licensing. ffmpeg pretty odd about it